# Mouse Clicked is not working

Tags: java, mouseclick-event

I'm trying to have a square change colors from black to white and from white to black whenever the square is clicked on. I use the mouseClicked function to do so, but the problem is that the mouseClicked is not clicking correctly. When I click on the bottom of one square, the square underneath of it is pressed.

Here's my mouseClicked code:

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                mouseX = e.getX();
                mouseY = e.getY();
                System.out.println(mouseX + ", " + mouseY + ", " + (screenW / squares));
                colorFlip();
            }
        });
```

My colorFlip code:

```
private void colorFlip() {
    for (int i = 0; i < cells.size(); i++) {
        Cell cell = cells.get(i);
        int x = cell.getX();
        int y = cell.getY();
        int side = cell.getSide();
        if (mouseX >= x && mouseX < x + side && mouseY >= y && mouseY < y + side) {
            if (cell.getR() == 0) {
                cell.setRGB(255, 255, 255);
            } else if (cell.getR() == 255) {
                cell.setRGB(0, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
    mouseX = -1;
    mouseY = -1;
}
```

And my cell initialization code:

```
   Cell(double xVal, double yVal, double sideVal) {
    x = xVal;
    y = yVal;
    side = sideVal;
}
```

Thanks, 
Pranav

Comment: Can you elaborate on "When I click on the bottom of one square, the square underneath of it is pressed."? What do you mean by bottom of the square?

Comment: Looks like you don't check the Z order of your cells or you have an off-by-one error. Use debugging techniques to check the content of your variables/objects while flipping a cell.

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder My program creates a 3x3 grid of squares, so by bottom of the square, I mean the bottom of one of the squares in my grid.

Comment: @Progman What do you mean by Z order and off by one error? And how would I use debugging to solve this?

Comment: @PranavSuby Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order for a definition of "Z order". In short you might have overlapping  squares, where you hit both squares with  one coordinate. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error for a definition of "Off-by-one error". You might check one coordinate too much or too few for your borders, reaching areas which you aren't supposed to do. You use the debugging feature in the IDE to check the contents of the variable while your code is running and check if the code is going where it is supposed to go.

Comment: @Progman Thanks, I'll look into that. I got a temporary solution by subtracting 23 from the y value and it works, but I would prefer a cleaner fix.